# How do you get the state of a youtube video on youtube.com?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that needs the state of the youtube video player, and [I'm aware of the existence of the API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?csw=1#Requirements) but my attempts to actually use it have been fruitless. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think you actually want the YouTube Data API.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: I don't think so because it says "The YouTube Data API (v3) lets you incorporate YouTube functionality into your own application." I just want to interact with the player already on youtube.com as if I were using the JS console.

Comment: Oh, I misread.  I thought you wanted the state of the video, not the player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for is that you have to call the API methods on this div and that wasn't made clear in the docs.

```
document.getElementById('movie_player');
```

Moreover if anyone else ends up here go ahead an read this:

[Insert code into the page context using a content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script/9517879#9517879)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to subscribe to the onStateChange event as described here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?csw=1#SubscribingEvents

The states of the player are described in the documentation for the onStateChange event on the same page.